# Android multithread client sockets with path/android-priority-jobqueue or AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I am using AsyncTask to execute my client sockets. However it is not the best approach for 10 or more paralell open connections. 
I therefore looked for a job queue/ threadpool manager and found https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue#dependencies

I need some examples for my usecase. Unfortunately, in the project itself there is only one HTTP Twitter example.

Please anyone, help.
Thanks.

Comment: which example du u want ?

Comment: doesn't matter anymore. I use rxJava and rxAndroid.

Comment: The link to jobqueue's dependencies doesn't make any sense. If the example is Twitter or something else doesn't matter - it all works the same. You should be able to realize this...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. It is actually really easy. I am using rxJava now and the problem with multithreading has become way more simpler. What I basically do is I create Observables that work like a TCP socket configuration. I then join 2 or more, depending on my connections and subscribe each to an Observer which will handle the outgoing and incomming TCP Socket communication.

Comment: How could rxJava be the solution for not understanding Android Priority Job Queue?